# mkdir from txt file with sub directories

Tags: terminal, macos

I m trying to make a folder structure from a list in a txt file and would also like to add additional subfolders.

text file is formatted like the below and called folders.txt

```
“Folder A”
“Folder B”
“Folder C”
```

I can use this

```
cat folders.txt | xargs mkdir
```

command successfully to create the folders but would also like to add subfolders to each folder from the text file without putting them in the text file itself. I though the command would be something like this

```
cat folders.txt | xargs mkdir -p /{“Subfolder A”,“Subfolder A”}
```

but i get `Read-only file system` error when i run this.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: First of all, stop using smart quotes. They're wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mkdir -p /…` is trying to create your folders at the root of the volume, which a normal user cannot write to.

This is because you're not creating subfolders. xargs adds arguments to the end of the command by default. Have xargs insert your folders into the command in the right place rather than at the end.

```
cat folders.txt | xargs -I§ mkdir -p §/{"Subfolder A","Subfolder A"}
```

Comment: Most people don't have easy access to the `§` symbol. You'd be better with something like the more typical `{}`

Comment: Thanks @grg your answer works perfectly for me.